# how to read from byte array to generate binary file

Tags: vbscript

Here a code snippet for downloading a binary file using VBScript:

```
...
Dim fs,ts
varByteArray = http.ResponseBody
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("filetowrite", True)
For lngCounter = 0 to UBound(varByteArray)
   ts.Write Chr(255 And Ascb(Midb(varByteArrary, lngCounter + 1, 1)))
Next
ts.Close
```

(full code can be found [here](http://www.ericphelps.com/scripting/samples/binarydownload/index.htm))

I am wondering about:

```
Chr(255 And Ascb(...
```

1. From my understandig `Chr` generates 2 bytes UTF-8, not one (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/145745). But wouldn't this be necessary for a correct byte output for a newly generated binary file?
2. Why do you mask 255 using an `And` operator with the number of a one byte ANSI character. What purpose does this have?

Comment: How VBScript represents strings internally and what is written to files are two different things.

Comment: Mm, so it seems like because of Midb->Ascb that there couldn't be any special unicode representations. Therefore the character after Chr would internally always be 0-255 | 0. Then, the character is given as one byte ascii to the textstream write. So the write process is then correct again.

Comment: A lot of that seems pointless to me who isn't going to have the ADO Library on a Windows machine these days?

Answer (score 0):

1. That code is not using "Option Explicit" so variable declarations are useless. It is using undeclared variables. Two declared and initialized variables are not used.
2. The "binary and" with 255 seems to serve no purpose

I downloaded a test file of 4 MB using 4 different methods

3. Using Chrome, the regular way
4. Using the ADO method in the script. Is very fast and is byte-identical to browser version (Hex comparison)
5. Using the AscB method with "binary and with 255". It is very, very, very slow but is byte-identical to browser version (Hex comparison)
6. Using the AscB method without "binary and with 255". It is very, very slow (but a little faster than 5) but is byte-identical to browser version (Hex comparison)

Bottom Line: That code works. Tries multiple methods to connect in order of preference, tries two methods to download in order of preference (it tries ADO first and only falls back to AscB method if ADO fails). I like that code.

Comment: I wouldn't see *"declarations are useless"* when `Option Explicit` isn't used, ideally you should be using `Option Explicit` but you should always declare your variables. Last thing you want is variables out of scope of functions etc., plus it makes it far easier to move to `Option Explicit` in the first place.